# changing the tint of the image in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimage

I am new to swift and trying to achieve this essentially, 
This image to 
[image]

This image ->

[image]

I am using this code [from here](https://gist.github.com/alexruperez/90f44545b57c25b977c4) to change the tint on image but do not get the desired output

```
func tint(image: UIImage, color: UIColor) -> UIImage
{
    let ciImage = CIImage(image: image)
    let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIMultiplyCompositing")

    let colorFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIConstantColorGenerator")
    let ciColor = CIColor(color: color)
    colorFilter.setValue(ciColor, forKey: kCIInputColorKey)
    let colorImage = colorFilter.outputImage

    filter.setValue(colorImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    filter.setValue(ciImage, forKey: kCIInputBackgroundImageKey)

    return UIImage(CIImage: filter.outputImage)!
}
```

If this is a noob question, apologies. I was able to do this easily in javascript but not in swift.

Comment: its your imageview or a multiple images

Comment: This image is being applied as a material

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hi you can use it the following way. First the UIImage Extension that you used needs some updates.
you can copy the code below for Swift 3

```
extension UIImage{
func tint(color: UIColor, blendMode: CGBlendMode) -> UIImage
{

    let drawRect = CGRect(x: 0,y: 0,width: size.width,height: size.height)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, scale)
    color.setFill()
    UIRectFill(drawRect)
    draw(in: drawRect, blendMode: blendMode, alpha: 1.0)
    let tintedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return tintedImage!
}
}
```

Then in your viewDidLoad where you are using the image
for example i used the image from IBOutlet imageWood

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.imageWood.image = self.imageWood.image?.tint(color: UIColor.green, blendMode: .saturation)
}
```

You will have to use the appropriate color and the images

The other [Extension](https://gist.github.com/fabb/007d30ba0759de9be8a3) i found

```
extension UIImage {

// colorize image with given tint color
// this is similar to Photoshop's "Color" layer blend mode
// this is perfect for non-greyscale source images, and images that have both highlights and shadows that should be preserved
// white will stay white and black will stay black as the lightness of the image is preserved
func tint(_ tintColor: UIColor) -> UIImage {

    return modifiedImage { context, rect in
        // draw black background - workaround to preserve color of partially transparent pixels
        context.setBlendMode(.normal)
        UIColor.black.setFill()
        context.fill(rect)

        // draw original image
        context.setBlendMode(.normal)
        context.draw(self.cgImage!, in: rect)

        // tint image (loosing alpha) - the luminosity of the original image is preserved
        context.setBlendMode(.color)
        tintColor.setFill()
        context.fill(rect)

        // mask by alpha values of original image
        context.setBlendMode(.destinationIn)
        context.draw(self.cgImage!, in: rect)
    }
}

// fills the alpha channel of the source image with the given color
// any color information except to the alpha channel will be ignored
func fillAlpha(_ fillColor: UIColor) -> UIImage {

    return modifiedImage { context, rect in
        // draw tint color
        context.setBlendMode(.normal)
        fillColor.setFill()
        context.fill(rect)

        // mask by alpha values of original image
        context.setBlendMode(.destinationIn)
        context.draw(self.cgImage!, in: rect)
    }
}


fileprivate func modifiedImage(_ draw: (CGContext, CGRect) -> ()) -> UIImage {

    // using scale correctly preserves retina images
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, scale)
    let context: CGContext! = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    assert(context != nil)

    // correctly rotate image
    context.translateBy(x: 0, y: size.height);
    context.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0);

    let rect = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: size.width, height: size.height)

    draw(context, rect)

    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image!
}
```

}

Using it like this

```
self.imageWood.image = self.imageWood.image?.tint(UIColor.purple.withAlphaComponent(1))
```

Comment: I used this method. I am filling up the entire image with green. I tried multiply, sourceIn, sourceOut as blend modes but all have same effect ... how do I get only the lines to change color? The original images alpha has to be multiplied right?

Comment: Are you using a .png or .jpg?
also you have to make sure that the image is transparent in the boxes and only the lines are visible so that the effect is applied only on the lines

Comment: it is a png .. the space between the lines is transparent (alpha 0)

Comment: try with this

self.imageWood.image = self.imageWood.image?.tint(color: UIColor.purple.withAlphaComponent(0.1), blendMode: .difference)

Comment: this is applying the tint on the empty spaces and leaving the lines the sam. I want the inverse operation. I am trying all the different blendmodes

Comment: .difference blend mode worked fyi .. thanks for your answer :)

Comment: @PavanK Also added another extension. You can try with this extension as well which is much more easier to manipulate and get the required results.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code, should work for you.

```
    if let myImage = UIImage(named: "imageName")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate) {
        myImageView.image = myImage
        myImageView.tintColor = UIColor.white
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your image is simple and only has one color. I would suggest making your image transparent except where the lines are, and then layer it on top of a white background to get your results.

It looks like you got the results you're after using drawing modes. There are also a number of Core image filters that let you apply tinting effects to images, as well as replacing specific colors. Those would be a good choice for more complex images.

Comment: The image is transparent except for the lines. SO is displaying it here with the white filled in.